# PHP Search Array in Array and add value

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following array:

```
Array $a
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Shoes
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Shirts
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Jeans
    )
)
```

And i've got this array:

```
Array $b
(
[0] => [1]
[1] => [5]
[2] => [6]
)
```

Now i want to find out, if one value of $b matches the [id] in $a. If so i want to add a new value ['hasID'] => true inside $a.

The solutions should look like this:

```
Array $a
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Shoes
        [hasID] => true
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Shirts
        [hasID] => false
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Jeans
        [hasID] => false
    )
)
```

My try was this:

```
    foreach($a as $ak => $av) {
        foreach($b as $bk => $bv) {     
            if($bv == $ak['id']) {
                $a[$ak]['hasID'] == true;   
            } else {
                $a[$ak]['hasID'] == false;
            }
        }
    }
```

That doesn't work so. I've tried hours. Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the first array and check if the value of `$arr['id']` exists under the second array of ids. If found, add a flag as true or 1 , else false or 0.

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>&$arr) //<--- As you can see I have  added & (Reason below)
{
   in_array($arr['id'],$arr2) ? $arr['hasID']= true : $arr['hasID']=false;
}

print_r($arr1);
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/137912)

**Reason** : To modify the array directly , you use the reference operator.

#### One-liner `array_walk()`

```
array_walk($arr1,function (&$v,$k) use($arr2){ in_array($v['id'],$arr2)? $v['hasID']=true : $v['hasID']=false; });
```

Comment: You've implemented a few things there that a newcomer might not understand; references & why `==` won't work over `=`.

Comment: @MackieeE, I hope I explained the reference thing. Thanks for the headsup.

Comment: Wow! This works and is short and sexy. And i've learnt something new with the reference operator. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @PascalCloverfield, Reduced the code even more down and added an `array_walk` version. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your try is not working because you use double == instead of simple = for value attribution. This should works :

```
foreach($a as $ak => $av) {
    foreach($b as $bk => $bv) {     
        if($bv == $ak['id']) {
            $a[$ak]['hasID'] = true;   
        } else {
            $a[$ak]['hasID'] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

However the solution with in_array is a better choice for performance reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array('1'=>'shoes','2'=>'shirts','3'=>'jeans');
$arr2 = array('0'=>'1','1'=>'5','2'=>'6');

$i = 0;
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$val)
{
    if($arr2[$i] == 1)
    {
        $ARR[$k][] = $k;
        $ARR[$k][] = $val;
        $ARR[$k][] = 'true';
    }
    else
    {
        $ARR[$k][] = $k;
        $ARR[$k][] = $val;
        $ARR[$k][] = 'false';
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ARR);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```